# Why is Apple team-id Shown as Different in Xcode Than on Apple Developer Page?

Tags: xcode, certificate, code-signing, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

It is my understanding that my Apple developer team id is a unique 10-character string that can be checked by visiting the Apple developer page like so:

[image]

However, I've noticed that the code in XCode shows a different id:

[image]

Note: The team selected above is NOT the "personal team."

Everything is running fine, but this apparent mismatch has me worried that something has gone wrong with my configuration.

I'm assuming that this id shown in XCode is supposed to be the same team-id under normal circumstances?  Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The team ID's don't necessarily match the signing certificate ID's. Developments IDs are randomly generated and assigned per user rather than per team. This is also confirmed here:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361392/why-is-my-ios-development-certificate-team-id-different-from-my-real-team-id

I have also seen edge cases where a VERY old app bundle identifier does not match the new style of team / app ID's, in which case you have to contact Apple to get new ones assigned (the downside to which is that your old user preferences / keychain items on user devices will not be accessible by the updated app with the new bundle ID)